# How do I turn off wobbling for sweetalert2?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

As soon as a sweetalert2 pops up, the 'X' inside the circle starts wobbling and then stops, which can get annoying. What property do I apply to the JavaScript to turn that off?
Why I asked this question again: I asked this question before, but it closed automatically because it said it needed "debugging details", and I don't know what that means. Maybe it might work this time.
Resources: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11

```js
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen-Sans, Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML is already in Developer Tools so there is no need for it, and this project can work without it.-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom class to the icon to remove all animations. Define the class somewhere that's loaded on the page:

```
.no-animate {
  animation: none;
}
```

then reference it

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'error',
  title: 'Oops...',
  text: 'Something went wrong!',
  customClass: {
    icon: 'no-animate'
  }
})
```